# Displaying TestNG error message in custom format in Jenkins

Tags: java, html, testng

I am trying to display custom message for failed test with TestNG framework for Jenkins.

In my test I do this:

```
Assert.fail("<h3>Test failure reason</h3></br>");
```

When I go to `TestNG Results` in Jenkins and click failed test, I can see this:

[image]

HTML tags are displayed on the page and `Test failure reason` message doesn't look like a header.

Is there any way to display any error message in custom format in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

The assertion failure messages are treated as text and I dont think the TestNG reports has the ability to parse them and show them as html tags. If you are after something like this, then you would need to build your own reporter implementation.